# Consuming JAX-WS Web Service - best practices?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

What is the best practice for consuming JAX-WS web service in a Java client? I am inclined to use *wsimport* to generate stubs. It means using JAXB. Please suggest.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that it's necessarily a best practice, but I definitely recommend using wsimport/JAXB generated stubs for consuming a SOAP service in the client. You could also use any number of other methods but they all boil down to two options:

1) have stub code generated that does all the XML and HTTP (or other protocol) work for me

2) concoct an XML message in a Java String and use various HTTP (or other protocols) methods to send that XML to the remote service. Then parse the result using some method (regex, custom parser, SAX, DOM, etc..)

In reality option 1 boils down to option 2, but you never see it.